# google-admin-sdk - Gmail Usage - Specific Definition Not Mentioned in API Guide

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Using the Reports API, I have made a simple command line app to return users with unused Gmail accounts. I am using the attribute accounts:last_login_time.

**I am writing to ask if this parameter includes the user's usage of the Gmail app for Android**

I'm concerned that my API call will falsely return users who only check their account via the android app as 'delinquent'.

Answer (score 0):

I think logging to your gmail regardless of medium is still counted as a log-in activity, hence the server will still take note of that. If you want to make sure, login a member test user account using Android Gmail app and make a request using 
[Login Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/login?customerId=C03az79cb
```

Check if it returns the time you logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail

You'll want to use the `gmail:last-interaction-time` to ascertain whether or not an account is delinquent. The reason is that access via IMAP/POP is counted independently of logon: `last_logon_time` is an accounts property, whereas user activity reports for Gmail tracks access time in general, as well as access times by protocol (POP, IMAP, WebMail). You can, of course, query both accounts & gmail in the same request with a comma-separated list of the appropriate *app-name:parameter* pairs.